# How to draw errorbar using pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, errorbar

I am developing a PyQt5 app, where I used pyqtgraph to make figures. I was wondering how to draw the error bars along with the data points in a GraphicsLayoutWidget. While it is very easy to plot data points using win.addPlot().plot(x_datay, y_data),  I can't find any documentation in the official pyqtgraph website about drawing error bar along with each data point in GraphicsLayoutWidget. Anyone has any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but I had the same issue and thought I would post my solution so that it might help others.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

w = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
w.show()

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10) % 3
top = np.linspace(1.0, 3.0, 10)
bottom = np.linspace(2, 0.5, 10)

err = pg.ErrorBarItem(x=x, y=y, top=top, bottom=bottom, beam=0.5)

plt = w.addPlot(row=0, col=0)
plt.addItem(err)
plt.plot(x, y, symbol='o', pen={'color': 0.8, 'width': 2})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the examples that come with pyqtgraph to see if that that's the error  [ErrorBarItem](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/errorbaritem.html) type you mean.

What you could do is, start up python and run:

```
import pyqtgraph.examples
pyqtgraph.examples.run()
```

Now you have all the pyqtgraph examples visible in a browsable window. Finally in the left navigation bar go to **GraphicsItems**

And there you have it. listed under ErrorBarItem is example code on how to implement ErrorBarItems.

Comment: Hi Jeroen. Thank you for your answer. You are right, we can use **ErrorBarItem** to plot error bar following what are provided in the example. The problem I had is plotting error bar in GraphicLayout widget. If plotting lines, we can easily do it this way: `l = pg.GraphicsLayout(border=(100,100,100)), p1 = l.addPlot(title="Plot 1"), p1.plot([1,3,2,4,3,5])`. But you cannot do the plotting for error bar in this way with GraphicLayout widget.

Comment: Please next time provide the code in your answer. As for your reply. You are not using the **GraphicsLayoutWidget**, but GraphicsLayout, which has a different use. [ http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/graphicslayout.html ] _Used for laying out GraphicsWidgets in a grid. This is usually created automatically as part of a GraphicsWindow or GraphicsLayoutWidget._

Comment: The docs on `ErrorBarItem` currently reside at https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/errorbaritem.html